# SCCM doesnt receive third party updates

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sccm-2012-r2

[image]

Hello Guys,,
When I Try to download updates, the below message is appear.
It refuse to download updates and update it

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error message and in some cases, below solutions/workaround works:

- Download the update separately and if it works, add to software update group before deployment.
- Turn off the anti-virus program running on the system which hosts the console.
- Use another account which has proper permission to download.

If all above are not helpful, review Patchdownloader.log, it will record some messages during patch downloading. This is always helpful for troubleshooting patch downloading issue. Also pay attention to SMSAdminUI.log which records console activities.